# Building AWS Lambda jar

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

What is the standard practice for creating AWS Lambda jar.

Should we bundle the dependencies as jars within the zip file or should the dependencies be unjarred and included as classes.

As far as I know it is the first option that holds true, but this doubt came to mind when I was following the AWS Tutorial of thumbnails and it eventually created a jar that had classes for dependencies (like Jackson) rather than bundling Jackson jar in the artifact.

Is there a sample AWS Lambda zip file that I can download and try (the one that has dependencies bundled as .jar files and not as .class files)

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-create-jar-pkg-maven-no-ide.html

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/create-deployment-pkg-zip-java.html

Comment: so basically you can either have a jar or a zip with a special structure

Comment: Thanks Mircea. I was exactly looking out for http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/create-deployment-pkg-zip-java.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should include the dependency jars in a `lib` subdirectory.  If you have a class `mypackage.LambdaFunctionHandler`, the zip file should have this basic structure:

```
.
|-- mypackage
|   +-- LambdaFunctionHandler.class
+-- lib
    |-- myjar1.jar
    +-- myjar2.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [maven shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) to build a shaded jar containing all your code and its external dependencies.

Simply add the following to the build plugins to your pom.xml:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Build. -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.shade.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <!-- Suppress module-info.class warning-->
                            <exclude>module-info.class</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    <plugins>
<build>
```

If you set 'minimizeJar = true', it will also filter out anything unnecessary for the jar execution, resulting in a smaller file size (which in theory, results in a shorter cold start time when the function is first invoked).